# How to get text value of HTML label in c# in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<label for="Rdb_0">Yes</label>
<label for="Rdb_1">No</label>
```

I want the values "Yes" or "No" to store in a variable for further use.

Comment: http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Comment: C# is a programming language and as such it does not have HTML Labels. You need to specify what Web framework you are using, e.g. `ASP.NET WebForms` or `ASP.NET MVC`. Without that, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @Peter B is right. While it's unknown what Web framework you are using your question is unanswerable. Also I think that your question is trivial and I think that you can quickly google the answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using WebForms the easiest is to change your ASPX to:

```
<label ID="myLabel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" for="Rdb_1">No</label>
```

and then in code behind:

```
myLabel.InnerText
```

However I would suggest you investigate using a label control  as that would be even easier to use.